# Get variable from another variable in Pascal

Tags: variables, dynamic, pascal

I have problem with PASCAL.

In Javascript I could do:

```
window.b = 'hello';
var a = 'b';

/* And I can get variable b having only variable a */

console.log(window[a]); // output = hello
```

How can I get the same result in Pascal ?

Thanks for answers in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pascal is a strongly typed compiled language, you cannot do this kind of variable/type manipulation as easily as you would do it in JS or Python. It's just not something you do in Pascal. In particular, Pascal has no built-in reflection capabilities, so it cannot interpret its own source code to know that by the string 'b' you mean the variable called `b` in the `window` object.

It cannot declare a typeless variable either - all variables **must** have a type, so `var a` is out of the question, and the compiler won't try and guess what you need.

I don't see what you would achieve doing this. Pascal is not meant to be used in such a dynamic way, you should not try and bend the language to your will - use it as it's meant to be used for best results.

Comment: Delphi and Free Pascal have some forms of RTTI, but that is mostly meant for streaming. Using the reflection that RTTI provides is a severe brake on performance though, so in general it is indeed better to avoid it.